# Multiple ListAdapters or a single one, using filtering (Android Performance)

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

> Try to focus on general "dos and donts" regarding lists, e.g. is
>   adding and removing 30 items of a 200 item list better then clearing
>   and repopulating? Or any other tips in this area - I cant really try
>   on my phone, to fast for that :-)

Is there any way to calculate the memory overhead / calculation power of list operations. The background is as following:

I have a list view on a page, the page has e.g. 3 Tabs at the bottom (All, Search, Recent). Now if you click on a tab, the listview should show you the approriate items.

There are two different approaches now, one is:

**Use a single ListAdapter, filter the items** accordingly
- If you click All, just put all items from the DB into it
- If you click Recent, just put the items which meet the requirements

**Use two (three..) ListAdapters**, one for each category
- If you click All, setAdapter() of list to the approriate one
- If you click Recent, setAdapter() to appropriate one

We are talking about a list of 200 items, which are complex objects created out of a database. When e.g. searching for an item, you enter part of the title, and the list should only show the appropriate items. The items will not be recreated, I would query for the IDs only, and use the buffered items (see later on datastructure).

What I am also not sure about is "where to filter", I could do it in the database (select from where title LIKE abc) and then EITHER:

- **remove not matching** items from the list and **add all matching** (but not included) items
- **clear** the whole list, **add all matching** items

Again, to clarify the structure of the App data:

- **Database** with raw simple entries (with IDs + title + ...)
- **HashSet** with complex entries, created once from DB, **readonly** + always all entries
- **ArrayList** of current entries shown in a listView

I hope you get my drift, I am trying to get a feel for "expensive" operations. Perhaps, as a last motivation to answer, I will write some cases down, and you can give an opinion about how costly they are:

1. Selecting N items (ID only) from DB with "title LIKE"
2. Iterating a list of 200 items with a "title.contains()" and using only matches
3. Removing 100 items from an arraylist SHOWN by an list view
4. Removing 100 items from an arraylist not shown, then connect and show

Thanks for any feedback, or any tips for bad practices. Especially possible event trigger problems by working on visible list elements, instead of doing it first "in the background" and then setting a new ListAdapter

Comment: Fom the comments, I think it would be better to change your accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have accepted an answer already, but I think I don't agree, because `ArrayList` has to copy all elements, if in the middle is an element added or removed.

I understand you already have a `HashSet` with all entries.

In that case, I believe the most efficient adapter is a custom `ListAdapter` inspired from [`ArrayAdapter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter)

- your adapter stores an `ArrayList mAllObjects` of all entries (for the "all" tab).
- your adapter stores an `ArrayList mRecentObject` of recent entries (for the "recent" tab)
- your adapter stores an `ArrayList mMatchObject` of matching entries (for the "search" tab)
- your adapter has two filters

  - the recent filter returns the `mRecentObject` list (and creates it if it does not exist already)
  - the match filter creates a new `mMatchObject` list and adds matching elements. There is no optimization to be done here. the `delete()`method on an ArrayList is O(n).

Comment: So did i understand you correctly, that in "simple speech" it is better to clear an ArrayList and fill with with values from the HashSet again, instead of removing 20 items one by one (resulting in possibly 20 copy actions) - I am not sure what you mean by the last sentence. And your answer is definitly better than the other one :-)

Comment: @Christian Last sentence explained: when you do `delete()` the 1st item in the `ArrayList`, there are 199 object moved (2nd to 1st, 3rd to 2nd, etc.). When you delete, the nth element, there are N-n operations. One delete takes O(N) operations. Same complexity if you add an element.

Comment: @Christian and yes, the arraylist will be faster if you deleteAll and add only matching elements (I'd be matching them from the mAllObjects, but you could also  query the DB and then looking up the corresponding entry in your HashSet).

Comment: I agree with @rds here. I didn't fully think through your backing implementation of the records in your views. Clearing the ArrayList and adding objects as necessary would be faster than many deletions from the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do with the whole list thing, but regarding `filtering`, you should do it on the database side (in the select statement you mentioned)... especially since this application is for mobile (given the comment at the top) and you would want to offload intensive operations to server side rather than leave them on mobile.

Comment: Two issues here. First I am working with SQlite DB, so the db is on the phone (it might still be faster then working on lists). The second one is the issue of complex objects. They exist already, so I AM doing the search (e.g. WHERE name LIKE) in the DB, getting back IDs, and then I need to use these IDs to "filter" or "create" the result list (from the HashSet where the complex objects are stored by their IDs) - hope this was understandable :-)

Answer (score 1):

Slight stab in the dark. From the (fairly cursory) ["Designing for Performance" document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html), it would seem that object creation, especially short-lived ones, have very high cost. I would interpret this as coming from two places: 1) object creation overhead (especially for complex objects), and 2) invoking the GC when these go out of scope or are explicitly destroyed.

Thus, as a starting point, I'd argue that you would want to do the work in the DB, and push the deltas to the view. So, per your original question, do:

- remove not matching items from the list and add all matching (but not included) items

I suppose you could write a synthetic benchmark for this to get a feel for the differences in speed. However, in my own code, I try and avoid short-lived objects as much as possible as suggested by the performance document. The impact of the GC is heavyweight, as it often will disturb the UI thread and make it hiccup as it goes about its work.

Comment: Thanks, this would fit nice with my architecture. I am actually create the "big objects" gradually (details when needed) and keep them alive forever - only query IDs afterwards and getting the object. If I find out more details I will update this post. For now lets just call it answered :-)

Comment: removing non matching elements means all elements following elements are copyed. This is far from optimal.

Comment: This comment is what I am looking for. So clear list and add all (e.g. 150) matchings from HashSet should be faster then removing 50 (of 200) items from the list.

Comment: The reasoning does not sound right to me. There is no object creation, in "remove not matching items from the list and add all matching (but not included) items", but there is none in "clear the whole list, add all matching items" either. However, there are much more comparisons and moving of objects in the underlying ararys.

Comment: The point @rds is trying to make, I think, is a good one. If your List implementation is an ArrayList, then deletions and insertions are not O(1). The underlying structure is an array, so iteration is fast, but delete is not since you have to shuffle all n+1 items when you delete the n'th item.

You might consider a [LinkedList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html) instead, which has much better insert/delete performance, but worse random access performance. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist).

Comment: @mchang Yes but no, because `LinkedList` has slow random access, and random access it used very often in `getView()`. So I think a `LinkedList`would be even worse -- that would slow down browsing the list (particularly when reaching the end) ; before it was slow only when the filter was applied